# Convergence of a sequence of linear bounded operators in $L_2(B(0,1))$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $B_1$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $L^2(B_1)$ such that $f_n$ converges weakly to some $f_0 \in L^2(B_1)$. Consider the sequence $T_n$ of operators defined by
$$(T_nu)(x)= \int_{B(0,|x|)}f_n(y)u(y)dy,~~~x \in B_1,~ u\in L^2(B_1),~ n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

I've managed to show that every $T_n: L^2(B_1) \longrightarrow L^2(B_1)$ is a bounded linear operator and that $T_nu \rightarrow Tu$ for every $u \in L^2(B_1)$ pointwise. Now, I'm asking myself if is it true that $||T_n-T||_{\mathscr{L}(L^2(B_1))} \rightarrow 0$. I guess the answer is no, but I can't figure out a counterexample. Also, is there any hypothesis that I could add in order to make  $(T_n)$ convergent in $\mathscr{L}(L^2(B_1))$?

Any suggestion or comment is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The norm convergence is not true in general: You can have $\|f_n\|=1$ always, but $f=0$. I am pretty sure that then your norm convergence does not hold.